# What's the Lisp `quote` special form in category-theoretical terms?

Tags: lisp, monads, quote, category-theory

How should I think of `quote` in the context of Category Theory? Is `quote` a monad? What kind of things is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it plays any role in category theory since it does not have anything to do with computation and everything to do with parsing and syntax. It is not a monad.

Imagine you want the string `5 + 1`, what do you do? Well you enclose it in double quotes like `"5 + 1"` in the code and suddenly the result isn't `6` anymore but the string `"5 + 1"`. Is `""` something special in category theory? Is it a monad? Don't think so since it tells the compiler to create such a data structure that results in that string. In Haskell `"hello"` is just fancy syntax sugar for `['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`. In most languages a string is just a series of consecutive bytes, often an array.

The quote special form performs the same operation syck that `'(+ 1 2)` isn't an expression anymore, but data. The compiler does `(cons '+ (cons '1 (cons '2 '())))` and store the pointer to that for everywhere you have some literal ending with `(+ 1 2)`. Because of that `(eq '(1 2) (cdr '(+ 1 2))` might be `#t` but `#f` is just as reasonable outcome since the compiler might not optimize for shared structure.

Moving forward you could imagine a fancy language that can dictate how the parser and compiler interpret literals. Almost all languages I know has string literals but if you made code to model complex numbers it would have been cool to say in the code that `3+5i` should become `tmp1 = make_complex 3 5` and that `tmp1` is to be put everywhere the literal `3+5i` exists in code. Why should numbers, strings, chars and perhaps regular expressions have special treatment?